# mnist digit Similarity model with different outputs every time

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

This model is going to predict Similarity of two mnist digits.when I run this code I always got new predicted value.
Some time to digit are not same but it returns a value as when I have same digits!!
I dont know where is the problem.

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import Input,Model

from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, concatenate, Dense

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(data, _), (_, _) = mnist.load_data()

digita =data[0].reshape(1,28, 28, 1)
digitb = data[11].reshape(1,28, 28, 1)

#plt.subplot(2,1,1)
#plt.imshow(data[0])
#plt.subplot(2,1,2)
#plt.imshow(data[10])



digit_input = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(digit_input)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
out = Flatten()(x)


vision_model = Model(digit_input, out)


digit_a = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
digit_b = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))


out_a = vision_model(digit_a)
out_b = vision_model(digit_b)

concatenated = concatenate([out_a, out_b])
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(concatenated)

classification_model = Model([digit_a, digit_b], out)

print(classification_model.summary())
print(f"digit Shape: {digita.shape}")

print("Value:",classification_model.predict([digita, digitb]))
```

The output is:

```
 Value: [[6.7214874e-06]]#first time
 Value: [[0.99795604]]#second time
```

Comment: ... [did you try googling?](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/)

Comment: You didn't even train the network, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I agree with @xdurch0 where us the model.fit() function? Unless you train your model no fairy is gonna come and put a few sparks in your code to make it run. If you do not have any knowledge you should attend a course...